# Google maps into a small rectangle

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I'm just starting to look into learning swift and iOS app making. I'm trying to make an app that will use google maps. So far looking at examples I created a map and set

```
 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(45.489434, longitude: -73.775858, zoom: 15)
 let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
 view = mapView
```

This works fine but covers up the entire screen, I would like to be able to set the map to the lower portion of the screen only for example so I can add other things to the top.

To do so I tried adding a view to my view controller that covers a smaller portion of the screen. This new view is a child of the main view that was already there. I then changed the class of this new smaller view to GMSMapView and linked it to  viewController.swift which created this.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var smallMap: GMSMapView!
```

I then assign my map to this smallMap view and my code now looks like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var smallMapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCNG-Qg6vtIL7pQ26go1hPy9mmhfEre5IU")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(45.489434, longitude: -73.775858, zoom: 15)

    smallMapView.camera = camera}
```

Is that the right thing to do to get a smaller map view?  When I run this I get libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException  error.

Anybody can help with what I'm missing?

EDIT: Here's what my Xcode view looks like

[image: view of xcode]

Thanks!

Comment: Is your outlet connected?

Comment: @NiravD Looks like it, if I right click a dot next to small map in outlets

Comment: If you have created outlet the there is no need to initialized it again in viewDidLoad remove or comment that

Comment: Outlet was created by dragging it from main.storyboard into viewcontroller which created the line you see. It's also outside of viewDidLoad not inside.

Comment: I'm saying is no need to initialized it in `viewDidLoad` remove or comment line  `smallMap = mapView`

Comment: It still crashes, and I'm not sure how it would put the map in that view without doing that anyway

Comment: @NiravD I added a screenshot of the info I have on Xcode, maybe that could help

Comment: What i'm telling is no need to reinitialize `smappMap` in viewDidLoad simply comment line     `let smappMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)`

Comment: Edited the initial question's code section with what you're proposing. I still get the same uncaught exception as before.